# Problem using jQuery with Firefox 4.0.1

Tags: jquery, firefox, jsf-2

I'm having trouble to get the following code to work with Firefox.

On other browsers this code results in the link being highlighted. But with Firefox I cant get it to even execute the js.

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink class="selector"     action="#" value="Create"   onclick="return false;"/>
        <h:commandLink class="selector"     action="#" value="Check"    onclick="return false;"/>
    </h:form>
```

And heres the js.

```
$(function()
{

    $(".selector").click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlightChoice');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

Also, weirdly enough without the 'return false' event onclick the page seems to refresh.

Comment: Try removing the onclick attribute. It shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Page refreshes without it, although it should not considering the js code.

Comment: $('form.selector') or also $('form\:selector')

Comment: Can you show the generated html code?

Comment: @Zippy right! that is the best reference with jsf. But there are some reference finesses, but findable here on StackO.[For Ex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038456/primefaces-javascript-and-jsf-does-not-work-well-together-or-am-i-doing-somethi)

Comment: Weird even with return false. It meight be 'cause the action-to-anchor is fired before the return false statement?  Might work using empty or forwarded actions? action=""  Not shure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
styleClass="selector"
```

instead of:

```
class="selector"
```

on your <h:commandLink />

Comment: Tested, didn't work. Although design wise it is better to use, thanks :)