# JSF + jQuery: how to achieve StackOverFlow collapsible comment box

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am creating a `Comment-Reply` system, similar to stackoverflow and I wonder how to implement it using JSF + jQuery. I have a dataTable, each row have a link and a textBox, and **once I click a link, only the textbox on that same row appear, and put focus on that textbox.**

```
<h:form id="userComment">
    <p:dataTable value="bean.comments">
         <p:column>
              <!-- link that if u click on it, the textbox below appear -->
              <h:inputTextarea id="reply" />      
         </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My main obstacle is that, normal jQuery user would do this: let assume the link `id` is **foo** then

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
    //Make the box with id `reply` appear and put focus on it
});
```

But since each row has a textbox call `reply`, there will be prependId before `reply` and `foo` like this `userComment:1:foo` or `userComment:1:reply`. Therefore `$('#foo')` and `$('#reply')` would not work

Comment: Use the `class` attribute. Element `id` s must be unique; classes can be repeated.

Comment: my requirement is that, only the textbox on the same row as the link I click appear. Can `class` help me solve that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` and `replace` the smart way.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.comments}" var="comment">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{comment.text}" />
            <h:outputLink id="add" value="#" onclick="showReply(this)">Add reply</h:outputLink>
            <h:inputTextarea id="reply" value="#{comment.reply}" style="display:none;" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

with

```
<script>
    function showReply(link) {
        jQuery(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(link.id.replace(/add$/, 'reply'))).slideDown(function() {
            jQuery(this).focus();
        });
    }
</script>
```

The `string.replace(/add$/, 'reply')` will replace `foo:1:add` to `foo:1:reply` and the PrimeFaces-supplied function `PrimeFaces.escapeClientId()` will escape it into a valid jQuery ID selector. Finally, you can do the focus in the callback.

Comment: it is just beautiful. Thank you. Now there is one thing that I find interesting, if I have the exact JSF like u have with the `h:form` outside, then I get this warning `The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>`. So i have to have a second `h:form`, wrap inside `h:inputTextarea` and that warning go away. Weird !!!